# User registration fully not working in Django

Tags: python, django

I am building a Django app with a sign up form. For this, I am adding additional fields to my model like this:

`models.py`

```
class studentInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="student")
    student_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, null=False, validators=[MaxValueValidator(99999),
                    MinValueValidator(10000)])
    major = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True, blank=False, default= '------')
```

And my `forms.py`

```
class UserReg(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email')

class StudentReg(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = studentInfo
        fields = ('student_id', 'phone', 'major', 'eof', 'arc')
```

And here is my `views.py` (It's definitely incorrect but I want to add it to show what I have tried)

```
def signup(request):
    print("in view")
    if request.POST:
        print("in post")
        userF = UserReg(request.POST)
        studF = StudentReg(request.POST)
        if userF.is_valid():
            userF.save()
            userInst = User.objects.get(username = userF.cleaned_data['username'])
            print(userInst.username)
            if studF.is_valid():
  
                studF.save()
                studInst = studentInfo.objects.get(studentInfo__student_id = studF.cleaned_data['student_id'])
                studInst.user = userInst
                studInst.save()
                return redirect('login')

        else:
            print('in the user invalid')
            print(userF.is_valid())
    else:
        userF = UserReg(request.POST)
        studF = StudentReg(request.POST)

    context = {'user':userF, 'student':studF}

    return render(request,'accounts/signup.html', context)
```

EDIT: Here is the signals file
`signals.py`

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_student(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

    
    if created:
        studentInfo.objects.create(user=instance)
```

`signup.html` -- rendering the form here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Signup Student</title>

    <body>
        <h1>Form goes here</h1>

        <form method = "POST" action="">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ userF.as_p }}
            {{ studF.as_p }}
            
            <input type="submit" value="save" />
        </form>

        
    </body>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

The problem I am running into is Django is creating a user but it isn't creating a student. It's requiring an already existing user to be created in order for the student object to be created. Is there a way to validate both forms and create a user and student when hitting the submit button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need signal anymore. get the id of saved user then add commit=false to append user id in form.

```
def signup(request):
    print("in view")
    if request.POST:
        print("in post")
        userF = UserReg(request.POST)
        studF = StudentReg(request.POST)
        if userF.is_valid():
            userF.save()
            if studF.is_valid():
                student_f = studF.save(commit=False)
                studfF.user = userF.id      
                studF.save() 
                return redirect('login')
```

Comment: I added this to the `views.py` Why am I getting 
 this: UnboundLocalError at /signup/
local variable 'userF' referenced before assignment

Comment: IMO it's better to add extended User models via signals to enable admin User creation etc.

Comment: The problem with signals are you cannot add the data the user provided. In order to do that,  you need to hit the database 2 times, but you can just achieve by just one.

Comment: @abhivemp just check your indention. Don't just copy paste the snippet.

Comment: Do you enconter any error to it? It should not raise an issue.

Comment: @vpdiongzon I tried your solution after fixing my errors and I still run into the problem. This time though, my userF came out to be invalid

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to connect signals in file which is not loaded. The quite simple solution is to remove `@receiver` decorator and use `signals.py` as functions module. You will need to do some action in `apps.py` though.

```py
class YourAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'name'
    verbose_name = 'verbose' # regular stuff

    def ready(self):
        # importing inside ready because apps are not loaded before that moment
        from django.contrib.auth.models import User
        from django.db.models.signals import post_save
        from .signals import create_student

        post_save.connect(create_student, sender=User)
```

And your `signals.py` should look like this:

```py
def create_student(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

    if created:
        studentInfo.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Comment: I am getting a csrf token error when running this. Do I have to import something in the `apps.py` ?

Comment: Do you include `{% csrf_token %}` in `<form>` in template? Or if you send with JS, do you attach `'X-CSRFToken'` header?

Comment: Yes, I added my csrf token in the form template. I can show my HTML file too in the question

Comment: And how do you send request? I don't see submit btn in form.

Comment: I just added a `<input type="submit" value="save" />` in the end

Comment: Well, that is sad problem but you should try @vpdiongzon approach first, since he is right about adding data right away